# Content type of a distant file

Tags: ruby, file, download, content-type

I would like to get the content type of a distant file because I have a problem when I download it. The content type is wrong. Here is my code to download a file

```
url = "http://my_url/my_file.mp4"
file = open(URI::encode(url))
content_type = file.content_type # => text/plain instead of video/mpeg or video/mp4
```

I tried the following code to get the content_type before but still not working:

```
url = URI.parse(url)
Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port){|http|  http.head(url.request_uri)['Content-Type']}
```

Does anybody have an idea?

**Edit**

Here is the code I use to find out which content_type it is..

```
MIME::Types.type_for(URI::encode(url)).map{|type| type.content_type}.join(' ')
# => "application/mp4 audio/mp4 video/mp4 video/vnd.objectvideo"
```

But here is the result with a video with sound track.. How am I suppose to only pink "video/mp4"? I can't check every file type to see what the result is.. It's endless.

Comment: Are you trying to find out what kind of file it is, or what the value of the Content-Type header returned by the server is?

Comment: Note: It's generally better to write `URI.encode(...)`. The `::` namespace navigator is intended for modules, classes and constants.

Comment: @Jordan I'm trying to know the Content-Type. Basically I would like to be sure that the uploaded file is what it supposed to be.. According to this content type I'll instantiate X or Y model..

Comment: I've just tested both your `open` code and your Net::HTTP code and found that both report the correct Content-Type, i.e. the value of the Content-Type header returned by the server. That leaves a few possibilities. Among them: 1. The server isn't returning the file, it's returning an error message as plain text (have you looked at the body of the response?); 2. The server isn't returning the file, it's returning some other document that's plain text; or 3. The server is returning the correct file, but with the wrong Content-Type header. I think 1 and 3 are the likeliest.

Answer (score 1):

Servers aren't obligated to tell you the correct content type and in many cases they'll get it wrong because it's not normally important. Most browsers provide considerable leeway on what they'll accept and process.

The only way to know for sure is to pull down the file and use a tool like [`file`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) to examine it. This has a fairly large database of different file formats and ways of identifying them.

The result of your request might be an HTML error message. You won't know until you verify the file's contents.

Comment: That's what I thought but when I do "open(..)" I create a temp file. I'm checking the content type of this temp file but it's a bad one.. Am I suppose to know exactly the content type of what I'll download before downloading it?

Comment: It's a messy world, so you can't be sure what you're going to get when requesting an arbitrary URL. If you've got control over the server and configure it correctly even then it's mostly matching filenames vs. MIME types, so it could be wrong.

Comment: FWIW you can pipe `curl` or `wget` to `file` and the pipe will short-circuit as soon `file` can identify it, so you don't have to download the whole file: `wget --quiet -O - http://... | file -` or `curl --silent --location http://... | file -` (cURL's `--location` option tells it to follow redirects; Wget does automatically).

Comment: Here is the result of both `wget` and `curl` requests: `/dev/stdin: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, iTunes AVC-LC`. Am I suppose to match that manually to the related Content Type?

Comment: If you have the `--mime` option for `file`, see if that helps. As always, `file --help` to the rescue.